# Can't view RGB image exported to Google Drive from Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, sentinel-2, rgb

I am trying to export a clipped satellite image from Google Earth Engine's Code Editor. I am able to see the image correctly within code editor, but am unable to open the exported image in Google Drive or on my computer if I download it.

My code is below, does anyone know what the problem might be?

```
/**
 * Function to mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band
 * @param {ee.Image} image Sentinel-2 image
 * @return {ee.Image} cloud masked Sentinel-2 image
 */
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

var geom = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[33.8777, -13.4055],
                                [33.8777, -13.3157],
                                [33.9701, -13.3157],
                                [33.9701, -13.4055]])

var collection = (ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
                  .select(['B4', 'B3', 'B2', 'QA60'])
                  .filterBounds(geom)
                  .filterDate('2016-01-01', '2016-06-30')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
                  .map(maskS2clouds)
                 )

var image = collection.sort('system:index', false).mosaic()
var image = image.clip(geom)

// Export the image, specifying scale and region.
Export.image.toDrive({
  scale: 10,
  image: image,
  description: 'example_image',
  fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',
  region: image.geometry().bounds().getInfo()['coordinates']
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming by "can't open it" you mean that all you're getting for an output is a black square (which is what I see when running your code). You can use the `visualize()` function to set visualization parameters. See the dataset's documentation for more on reflectance units. Add the following to the bottom of your code and you'll have an RGB product.

```
var imageRGB = image.visualize({bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 0.3});
print("rgb",imageRGB);

Export.image.toDrive({
  scale: 10,
  image: imageRGB,
  description: 'example_image_RGB',
  fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',
  region: image.geometry().bounds().getInfo()['coordinates']
});
```

Comment: Hi JepsonNomad, that seemed to do the trick.Thanks a lot!